# InvalidPasswordCipherException when using com.ibm.websphere.crypto.PasswordUtil.decode

Tags: java, websphere, aes

I'm using the following version of WebSphere:

```
Launching defaultServer (WebSphere Application Server 19.0.0.6/wlp-1.0.29.cl190620190617-1530) on IBM J9 VM, version 8.0.5.37 - pxa6480sr5fp37-20190618_01(SR5 FP37) (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server defaultServer has been launched.
```

I've added the following to `build.gradle`:

```
compile("com.ibm.websphere.appserver.spi:com.ibm.websphere.appserver.spi.kernel.service:1.5.15")
```

In `bootstrap.properties`, there is an AES encoded string:

```
user@service-pod:/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer$ cat bootstrap.properties 
SECRET="{aes}AJIZlX1899cct50fB2yUIcNdD5rp0yVhxtPnNKyuShGQh0T+VBzxnfU5G1S9hCYQioa3/hMj+qPAUnliv96B6aFAsWnGk7RiY42yslztDT6Y"
```

Which was encoded using: `securityUtility encode --encoding=aes $PLAINTEXT`

But when I try to decode the string from within the Java Web Application using:

```
System.out.println(PasswordUtil.decode(System.getProperty("SECRET")));
```

I'm getting this exception:

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: com.ibm.ws.crypto.util.InvalidPasswordCipherException
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ws.crypto.util.InvalidPasswordCipherException
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Suggest editing title, it seems to suggest you're getting an InvalidPasswordCipherException, you're getting a NCDFE instead.

Comment: Maybe server.xml needs <feature>passwordUtilities-1.0</feature>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`server.xml` needed:

```
<feature>passwordUtilities-1.0</feature>
```